# How to shortcut diamond character in vim

Tags: vim, mapping

In the dictionary file, which I am editing I often need to insert character *"◊"* on place of <>. Is there a way to map *"◊"* to some key so that I press "r" for replace and then my_shortcut to have <> replaced by *"◊"*?
I found a way to make imap mapping in .vimrc:

```
:imap <> ◊
```

But changing to inset mode is sub-optimal, would that be possible to make it all in **replace** mode and what should I write in .vimrc for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With thhe following map

```
:map r<> :%s/<>/◊/g<CR>
```

you can press `r<>` which will replace all occurences of <> with ◊ in the current buffer.

The map (or rather the substitution that is invoked with it) will give you an
error `E486` if the pattern is not found. If you don't want such an error, you'll
want to specify the `e` flag to the substitution command:

```
:map r<> :%s/<>/◊/ge<CR>
```

You can place one of these mappings into your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That worked great, with one change - I do not need to make sweeping changes for whole document, that scares me - make changes just for that instance. So,I take off "%" from equation.
map r<> :s/<>/◊/ge<CR>.
This still helps me  to easily replace <> with diamond char "◊" without distracting from vim window to searching it in some X application, like web browser.

Answer (score 5):

you can also use the digraph feature of vim, press CTRL-K followed by cD and you get a diamond. Or if CTRL-K is mapped to something else (some scripts tend to remap it) you can `:set digraph` and use `c <BS> D` in insert mode.

Comment: Vim is like text Photoshop, so much features... I haven't heard of "digraph feature". But that indeed works!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using an abbreviation for it? You can do:

```
:abbr <> ◊
```

And then each time you type <> followed by space (or any non-keyword character) in insert mode, it will be replaced with ''◊''.